# Bulletpoint spacing and linebreak start position with NSHTMLTextDocumentType

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios7, nsattributedstring, textkit

WIth iOS 7 came `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`, which Im using the code below to parse html and show it in a `UITextView`. It works perfectly, except with bullet points.

How can I both change the spacing on each side of the bulletpoints(the space between
the bulletpoint and the `UItextView` left border and the space between the bulletpoint
and the text to the right of it)?

Also, more importantly. If the text continues on the next line, I also need it to continue at the same x position like the line above it where the bullet point text started. How can I achieve this?
(Second line indentation)

I have tried using all kinds of css, but it seems that `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is still fairly limited. All I managed to to is change the color of just lists.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
_textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

NSString *testText = @"<p><b>This is a test with:</b></p><ul><li>test test test
test test test test test test test test test test <li>test test test test test
test <li>test test test test test <li>test test test test test test test test
test test test test <li>test test test test test test test test <li>test test
test test test test <li>test test test test test test test test test
</li></ul>";

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSData *htmlData = [testText dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];

    _attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlData
    options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    // Paragraph style
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 0;
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0f;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 30.0f;
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 20.0f;

    // Adding attributes to attributedString
    [_attributedString addAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}
                              range:NSMakeRange(0,_attributedString.length)];
    [_attributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
               range:NSMakeRange(0,_attributedString.length)];

    // Setting the attributed text
    _textView.attributedText = _attributedString;
```

Comment: What are you converting the text into html and then again converting back to bullet style. You can directly show the bulleted points if you have the NSDictionary of NSmutableArray of data with you

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to cease a mutable paragraphStyle and then set its indents, like:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *const bulletParagraphStyle = [paragraphStyle mutableCopy];
bulletParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20;
bulletParagraphStyle.tailIndent =20;
```

then set this paragraph style on ONLY the range of the text that includes the bullet points.

(It's going to be a bit clumsy to try to start with the HTML, I'd think: if you want to stay with that route maybe break it up into two HTML strings, one of the bullet list and one for the header, so you can set the different properties more easily.)